# Using bokeh with JQuery tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, bokeh

If I render my page without the Bokeh js at http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh-0.7.1.min.js my JQuery tooltips on a bunch table cells work OK. But if I include the Bokeh js, I get the error: `TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function`. What's going on? How can I get my Bokeh graph and JQuery tooltips to work on the same page?
OK... thanks to @Pointy, I've found the correct order to import the JS libraries:

1. http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh-0.7.1.min.js
2. http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js
3. http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js

Unfortunately for me, my Django template inherits from several base templates before importing Bokeh and so the main JQuery library (2, above) has already been imported by the time it sees (1)... is there a way to import Bokeh's JS without breaking the JQuery already imported?

Comment: That library you linked to looks like it might include a huge number of other libraries, including a version of jQuery.

Comment: Sure does... but the tooltips don't work even if I include _only_ the Bokeh JS.

Comment: Well if you import jQuery, and then your tooltip library, and *then* the bokeh file, it will overwrite the already-installed version of jQuery with its own. That will wipe out the modifications that your tooltip library made. Try importing just that bokeh file and *then* your tooltip library after it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Pointy. I've edited my question and I'm converging on a solution, I think.

Comment: Importing jQuery multiple times is always going to be highly risky and fragile. You're now importing another copy of jQuery, and for all we know that might cause similar breakage inside other stuff that Bokeh relies on.

Comment: Good point: I'm hoping a Bokeh developer will swing by and tell me how to import Bokeh without breaking my tooltips...

Comment: I believe this issue has been finally completely fixed in the latest dev build (as of 2015/03/05)